# What is "Data to restore" and why is it using mobile/Wi-Fi data?

Tags: 8.1, cellular-data, datasense

I was looking at data usage in the Data Sense app on my Lumia 920 (running WP 8.1 dev preview), and noticed that one of the entries in the list was called "Data to restore", with non-trivial amounts of data used:

[image]

What exactly is this? It sounds like this might be for data restored from cloud backups when upgrading or resetting the OS, but a) I always do this sort of thing on Wi-Fi, and b) the last time I did this was back in April (upgrading to the 8.1 preview), whereas the numbers in Data Sense are only for the month of May.

So what else can be included in this entry? And perhaps more importantly, how can I control when this happens, to make sure it doesn't burn through my monthly mobile data limit?

Comment: Ok, 92 MB is nothing. Just look at screenshot. How to stop it? It used over half of my mobile data...
http://i.stack.imgur.com/zPpE8.jpg Anyone nows how to stop it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It sounds like this might be for data restored from cloud backups when upgrading or resetting the OS, but a) I always do this sort of thing on Wi-Fi...

You are referring to when you download a backup from the cloud to restore the phone. However, periodically, WP has to **upload the existing state of your phone to the cloud**.

Items uploaded may include (and not limited to) themes, backgrounds, passwords, IE settings, application data, call tags, messages.

I suspect some network data is being used for the more critical components of the backup.  There is likely some hierarchy in place for what MUST be backed up and what MAY be backed up.

The period of time over which `Data to restore` has accumulated `11 MB` should give you a sense as to whether you need to be worried about it burning through your data.

Comment: It's the total amount of data (11 + 81 = 92 MB) that I'm concerned about - just because the majority of it has been on Wi-Fi this month doesn't mean that'll be the case every month. Your answer makes sense, though - I don't know why I didn't think of *uploaded* data myself :)

Comment: Hence you should monitor the behaviour over the coming weeks :)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't really answer the crucial part of the question which is: "And perhaps more importantly, how can I control when this happens, to make sure it doesn't burn through my monthly mobile data limit"?  
I’ve just burned over half a gig of cellular data in a week with this, that’s never happened before and I haven’t (knowingly) changed any settings for months.